# User blocked in AD by some windroid device

Tags: active-directory, logging, blocking

We have a user that is constantly blocked. We checked the logs in the domain controllers and all the information shown is that a WINDROID device is the source. How can I know which device is causing this? Is there a way to analyze this more deeply?

Comment: You can be pretty sure this is the users mobile phone. Those kinds of lockouts are commonly because of exchange sync to a phone after a password change.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I suppose if it's 'WINDROID device' then check you mail server (Exchange?)
enable netlogon on it:

```
nltest /dbflag:2080ffff
```

Netlogon.txt file is created in %systemroot%/debug directory

correlate timestamps inside log with time when account lockout happens...

don't forget to disable netlogon logging at the end

```
nltest /dbflag:0
```

Also you can try using free tool [Netwrix Account Lockout Examiner](http://lp.netwrix.com/troubleshooting_of_account_lockouts.html) it does simplify investigation